# How can I declare an Enum in TypeScript that will map to environment-defined global properties?

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums

I have an environment with several constants globally:

```
TOP = 1
TOP_RIGHT = 2
RIGHT = 3
BOTTOM_RIGHT = 4
BOTTOM = 5
BOTTOM_LEFT = 6
LEFT = 7
TOP_LEFT = 8
```

---

It is clear to me that these 8 constants are not just arbitrary constants, but actually a set of directions.  Therefore, I would like to have them be of the `DIRECTION` type, so that I can do things like this:

```
let test: DIRECTION = TOP_LEFT;
```

An `enum` type seems to be the most logical way of accomplishing this, but I encountered the following problem:

---

I attempted to implement this behavior previously, with some difficulty.

```
src/main.ts(1,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'TOP_LEFT'.
```

Typescript Files:

main.ts:

```
let test: DIRECTION = TOP_LEFT;
console.log(test);
```

direction.d.ts:

```
declare enum DIRECTION {
    TOP = 1,
    TOP_RIGHT = 2,
    RIGHT = 3,
    BOTTOM_RIGHT = 4,
    BOTTOM = 5,
    BOTTOM_LEFT = 6,
    LEFT = 7,
    TOP_LEFT = 8,
}
```

Ignoring the compile error, the JavaScript result of running "tsc" (a.k.a. the transpiled code) looks like it it will access the pre-defined global property:

```
let test = TOP_LEFT;
console.log(test);
```

How can I obtain such output in a TypeScript-friendly way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You interpret the use of enums wrong. Enum do not exists in the same way in Javascript as to, for instance, c++. When the compiler compiles your enum declaration, a new variable is created in its place with mappings to retrieve the key and the value.

The following enum...

```
enum Example {
    One,
    Two
}
```

...is the TypeScript equivalent of the following Javascript object:

```
var Example;
(function (Example) {
    Example[Example["One"] = 0] = "One";
    Example[Example["Two"] = 1] = "Two";
})(Example || (Example = {}));
```

What you seem to be after is a set of constants that are mapped to a type. You can declare literal types in TypeScript. e.g. `declare type Direction = 1 | 2 | 3 ... | 8;`. However, this is not really useful when you refactor your code or add more direction constants. Luckily you can use the `typeof` keyword to get the values of an object. You can declare your `Directions` type as followed:

```
const TOP = 1
const TOP_RIGHT = 2
const RIGHT = 3
const BOTTOM_RIGHT = 4
const BOTTOM = 5
const BOTTOM_LEFT = 6
const LEFT = 7
const TOP_LEFT = 8

declare type Direction =
    typeof TOP |
    typeof TOP_RIGHT |
    typeof RIGHT |
    typeof BOTTOM_RIGHT |
    typeof BOTTOM |
    typeof BOTTOM_LEFT |
    typeof LEFT |
    typeof TOP_LEFT;

const dir: Direction = TOP_LEFT; // or = 8
```

Variables declared with this type of `Direction` must have a matching value to the type, e.g. in your case 1 through 8.

However, I'd rather use enums instead of declaring a bunch of global variables.

Answer (score 1):

You've declared an ambient enum: [enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html). They are generally used to provide type information for a pre-existing type - e.g. one defined in an imported js library. If you look at the transpiled code, you see it hasn't
actually emitted a lookup of any type.

The normal way of declaring an enum would be:

```
 enum DIRECTION {
    TOP = 1,
    TOP_RIGHT = 2,
    RIGHT = 3,
    BOTTOM_RIGHT = 4,
    BOTTOM = 5,
    BOTTOM_LEFT = 6,
    LEFT = 7,
    TOP_LEFT = 8,
}
```

which would generate:

```
var DIRECTION;
(function (DIRECTION) {
    DIRECTION[DIRECTION["TOP"] = 1] = "TOP";
    DIRECTION[DIRECTION["TOP_RIGHT"] = 2] = "TOP_RIGHT";
    DIRECTION[DIRECTION["RIGHT"] = 3] = "RIGHT";
    DIRECTION[DIRECTION["BOTTOM_RIGHT"] = 4] = "BOTTOM_RIGHT";
    DIRECTION[DIRECTION["BOTTOM"] = 5] = "BOTTOM";
    DIRECTION[DIRECTION["BOTTOM_LEFT"] = 6] = "BOTTOM_LEFT";
    DIRECTION[DIRECTION["LEFT"] = 7] = "LEFT";
    DIRECTION[DIRECTION["TOP_LEFT"] = 8] = "TOP_LEFT";
})(DIRECTION || (DIRECTION = {}));
```

You'd then use it like so:

```
const t: DIRECTION = DIRECTION.TOP_LEFT;
```

Comment: what if I don't want to access it with ```DIRECTION.TOP_LEFT``` but instead with ```TOP_LEFT```?

Comment: then just declare a bunch of ```consts```